# How do I Filter a Measure in a Graph in Power Bi based on a date

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

i have a bar Chart in Power Bi , where i want filter a certain Measure based on a Date.
It only should shown for every month who is not after than a certian date.
In my example its the end of June

i tried with Measures but it gives too much before.

```
Total Sales Filtered = CALCULATE([Total Sales],FILTER('Date','Date'[Date]<MAX(ClosedMonthsDates[Date])))
```

[image]

Where is my Mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i figured out i just forget the equal ^^

```
Total Sales Filtered = CALCULATE([Total Sales],FILTER('Date','Date'[Date]<=MAX(ClosedMonthsDates[Date])))
```